# Any way to control VueRouter Smoothscroll-Speed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I can achieve `smooth-scroll` `router-links` with:

```
  <router-link :to="{ hash: 'home' }">Home</router-link>
  <router-link :to="{ hash: 'about' }">About</router-link>
```

and `router.js`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

import Home from "../vue/home";
import About from "../vue/about";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter ({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
        {path: "/", name: "home", component: Home},
        {path: "/about", name: "about", component: About},
    ],
    scrollBehavior(to, from,  savedPosition) {
        return {
            selector: to.hash,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        }
    }
});
```

The `smooth-scroll` effect is a bit slow compared to `vue's` `v-smooth-scroll` class. Is there any way to control the `smooth-scroll` speed of `VueRouter`?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Vue Router's Smooth Scrolling in implementing the native browser API `ScrollToOptions.behavior`. This is controlled by the client's browser. This can differ from system to system.